# A far away place

Tags: expressions

Is there an English idiomatic expression to indicate a place which is very far away from the speaker's location?

Something like

> in the middle of nowhere

but not necessarily implying that the place is isolated, just that it is far.

EDIT: an example sentence could be

> I saw a nice house for rent but it's not good for me: it's really *[too far away]*

Comment: If you provide more information about what context it's being used in, perhaps with an example sentence, it might be easier to give relevant answers.

Comment: A *faraway* place is *far away*.

Comment: @Jon Purdy: obviously, but I was looking for an idiomatic expression.

Comment: No no, I was just making the distinction between *faraway* and *far away*.

Comment: @Jon Purdy: sorry, I didn't notice :)

Comment: If you are talking only about a **great distance**, rather than isolation, there's **far, far away**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit:

As the question changed, I will now propose a more updated answer:

> In the backwoods

[Backwoods meaning:](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/backwoods)

> an area that is far away from any towns

Otherwise, "in the middle of nowhere" will do just as fine.

Edit: Due to the OP's desire, I would like to add an additional option, which although not idiomatic English, could be used to describe a far away place as well:

> A mile and a day/Peter's place is a mile and a day away!

Comment: Hope that one is specific enough! :)

Comment: That's a nice answer. Actually, if you could revert your edit, I liked `A mile and a day` even more!

Comment: @nico: "A mile and a day" might be nice, but it's not idiomatic English.

Answer (score 6):

There aren't many idiomatic phrases that convey distance without also conveying, or at least hinting at, isolation. The only one I can think of that meets your requirements is "**off target**" or, if it's *very* distant, "**way off target**".

Less idiomatic, but frequently used (in the UK at least) is the expression "**it's miles away**". Often this is used to mean "it's too far" regardless of the actual distance.

Others that spring to mind that haven't been mentioned in other answers have slightly different meanings:

- in the sticks (= in the countryside)
- off the beaten track ( = away from main transport links / hard to travel to or find)

Answer (score 5):

If you want to imply a populated area instead of a more rural setting, you could use **clear across town**.  I would drop the word "really" to make your example:

> I saw a nice house for rent but it's not good for me: it's **clear across town**.

Comment: Neat, and it's doesn't imply isolation.  Have a +1 on me.

Answer (score 3):

Another one I might use almost as much as **in the middle of nowhere** is

**The back of beyond**.

Comment: FYI in Australia you can say "the back of Burke" ...

Answer (score 3):

Most of the idiomatic phrases that spring to mind also have connotations of isolation (in particular both *in the backwoods* and *the back of beyond* do, despite being lovely phrases).  The phrases which don't imply isolation tend to be rather more prosaic:

> **some way off, a way away, a fair distance**

Comment: Spot on - ALL of the other answers offered to date have connotations of isolation.

Answer (score 2):

I'm from the midwest USA and I often use *[Timbuktu](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Timbuktu)* as a synonym for the middle of nowhere.

Answer (score 1):

In the US Northeast, we'd say "it's **out in the boondocks**" to mean it is far from town.

Comment: +1 for _[boonies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boondocks)_. Had no idea it was of Filipino origin, though.

Comment: Really? I had no idea either.

Comment: "Out in the sticks" is a similar expression in British English.

Answer (score 0):

The generic term I would use is "remote." That has the implication of "too far for me."

Answer (score 0):

In the context of the original example:
"I saw a nice house for rent but it's not good for me: it's **quite a drive**..."

I hear this when people are discussing daily commutes. It is probably British, and perhaps local to South-East England.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few proposals:

- on the edge of the world
- on the other side of the world
- on the far side of the world.
- at the end of the earth
- thousands of miles away.
- at the other end of the planet.
- at the ends of the earth.

Answer (score 0):

"Off the beaten path" often turns up in [travel websites](https://demopublic.magnolia-cms.com/tour-type~offPath~.html)

[Meaning](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=off%20the%20beaten%20path)